# How to map model classes so that there is a relationship between collections?

Tags: c#, mongodb, model-view-controller

i'm trying to learn Mongodb but have run into a few problems, i thought to specify a relationship, you will have to include it within the bigger class. i.e my idea is that one house can have many repair requests whereas a repair request can only have one house attached to it.

What i have tried is by adding a reference to a list of home repair requests under the houses' class properties.

```
         public class House
{
    public object id { get;  set; }
    public string Address { get;  set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }

    public IList<repairrequests> Repairs { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Repair requests classes is as follows:

```
public class repairrequests
{
    public enum RequestCatogory
    {
        Carpentry,
        Ceiling_repair,
        Ceramic_tile_repair,
        Door_Repair,
        Drywall_installation,
        Drywall_repair,
        Electrical_wiring,
        Fence_Fixing,
        Flooring_installation,
        General_Maintaniance,
        Gutter_Cleaning,
        Gutter_Repair,
        Home_inspections,
        Roofing,
        Trash_Removal,
        Window_Installation,
        Window_repair,
        other
    };

    public Object id { get; set; }
    public string requestMessage { get; set; }

    public string requestDescription { get; set; }

    public RequestCatogory type { get; set; }
}
```

Through this i expected when i created the controller for the house and view for creating the house. That there would also be options for adding a requests alongside it however only the main properties were shown.